# Error while creating wheel while installing packages in Mac

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-wheel

This is the error I receive while installing packages from a file using `pip install -r req.txt`

Then it tried building wheels for collected packages: `blis`; `cytoolz`; `murmurhash`; `preshed`; `regex`, and I got a long error list.

````
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  In file included from Python3/_regex.c:46:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  In file included from Python3/_regex.c:46:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
  #error architecture not supported
   ^
  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  20 errors generated.
  error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for regex```

Is something wrong with MacOS side because it is giving me bizarre errors.
Any leads appreciated.
````

Comment: [macos] should ***not*** be used for this purpose! Read the usage guidance. For now, I've suggested and edit.

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 this is related to the macos sdk so the tag being appropriate is a little bit of a grey area

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. My edit has not been approved yet, so I will change it to add back the tag and improve other things.